# Why \Box is uppercase?

Tags: equations, symbols

I read LaTex formula syntax document at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) and [KaTex](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/function-support.html), and found `B` of `\Box` is uppercase, not `\box`.

(1) Is there any reason that only `\Box` has uppercase in box family? It's very rare that only `\Box` has uppercase in whole TeX equation symbols.

(2) I'm developing LaTeX parser. Could it be any problem if I treat `\Box` as case-insensitive?

Comment: Yes! That would be a problem! It would conflate the primitive `\box` with the macro `\Box`.

Comment: Are you aware that TeX is not LaTeX? I'm confused as to why you are reading a document about LaTeX syntax if you are developing a TeX parser. But I'm pretty confused as to why you're trying to develop the latter if you don't (excuse me) know more than this about TeX.

Comment: @cfr // well, I agree with that I confused TeX and LaTex. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\box` is a TeX primitive, which is why the uppercase version is used as a symbol. And the language is case sensitive. Frankly, if you don't already know this, you are unlikely to be able to write a "TeX parser".

You may want to start by reading the TeXbook.

For some relevant questions on the site see:

- [Is there a complete modern book which explains how a TeX parser works?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244705/2693)
- [Is there a BNF grammar of the TeX language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4201/2693)